# Row-wise assignment of values to multiple columns

Tags: r

PROBLEM STATEMENT: Generating dummy variables based on values in multiple columns.

To assign values (more like dummy variables) to columns based on their presence in other “multiple columns". The following code uses data frames.

**Explanation:**

- V2 column represents value 2.  If the variables A1 or A4, either has
  value 2 then V2=1 and V1, V3:V12=0
- Similarly if A1=1 and A2 =4, then
  V1=1 ,V4=1 and V2,V3, V5:V12=0

Code is given to explain the output desired.

```
set.seed(12345)
df<- data.frame(A1=c(1L,2L),A2=LETTERS[1:3],A3=round(rnorm(4),4),A4=1:12)
df
names= paste0("V",c(1:12))
df[,c(names)]=0
for ( i in 1:nrow(df)){ df[i,c(names)]=match(c(1:12),df[i,c("A1","A4")])}
df[,c(names)][!is.na(df[,c(names)])]=1
df[,c(names)][is.na(df[,c(names)])]=0
df
```

I would like to have suggestions for code using data table : = operator so that process can be faster. Thanks

Comment: Instead of the many lines, you can just do `cbind(df, +(sapply(1:12, function(i) i==df['A1']|i==df['A4'])))`

Comment: Thanks akrun.Any alternate in case the number of columns are many and I would like to use either column range ( numeric) or a vector of column names instead of 'A1', 'A4'?

Comment: If there are many columns, we can place it in a list

Comment: i.e. `+(Reduce('|', lapply(df[c(1,4)], function(x) sapply(1:12, '==', x))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop the columns 'A1' and 'A4' of `df`, compare with the values 1:12 with `sapply`, Use `Reduce` with `|` and collapse the `list` output to a single matrix.  The `+` is for converting logical matrix to binary format.  In the last step we `cbind` with the original dataset

```
cbind(df, +(Reduce('|', lapply(df[c(1,4)], function(x) sapply(1:12, '==', x)))))
```

---

Another `base R` option without looping will be `table`.  We `unlist` the columns of interest i.e. 'A1', 'A4', get the `table` with `1:12` values, double negate (`!!`) to make '0' values FALSE and all other TRUE, use `+` to coerce the logical matrix to binary `1/0`, and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
subDF <- df[c('A1', 'A4')]
newdf <- cbind(df, +(!!table(rep(1:12, ncol(subDF)), unlist(subDF))))
colnames(newdf)[5:ncol(newdf)] <- paste0('V', 1:12)
newdf
#    A1 A2      A3 A4 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
#1   1  A  0.5855  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
#2   2  B  0.7095  2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
#3   1  C -0.1093  3  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
#4   2  A -0.4535  4  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
#5   1  B  0.5855  5  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
#6   2  C  0.7095  6  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
#7   1  A -0.1093  7  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0
#8   2  B -0.4535  8  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0
#9   1  C  0.5855  9  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0
#10  2  A  0.7095 10  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0
#11  1  B -0.1093 11  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0
#12  2  C -0.4535 12  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1
```

---

We can also use `data.table`.  I am not sure whether this is very efficient as we do `table` inside the `data.table`.  The approach would be to first convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `unlist` the columns specified in the `.SDcols`, get the  `seq_len` of number of rows (`.N`) i.e. 1:12 in the example, replicate (`rep`) it by the `length` of 'nm1', and get the `table`.

We create a `data.table` from the `table` class (`split(tbl..`), by looping through the columns using a `for` loop, we `set` the values to binary `0/1`.  The `set` approach is efficient as it avoids the overhead of `[.data.table`.  Later, we can `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c('A1', 'A4')
tbl <- setDT(df)[, table(rep(seq_len(.N),length(nm1)), unlist(.SD)), .SDcols=nm1]

dt1 <- setDT(split(tbl, col(tbl)))[]
for(j in seq_along(dt1)) {
       set(dt1, i=NULL, j=j, value=+(!!dt1[[j]]))
}

cbind(df, dt1)
```

Comment: Use of table inside data.table worked very well for my large dataset. Only introduced setnames(dt1,names(dt1),colnames(tbl)) before cbind. Thanks

Comment: we could use as.data.frame.matrix(dt1) to retain table values